# Loop json parsed data

Tags: jquery

I have this data:

```
[
   [
      {"id":"1", "sentiment":"0", "name":"Company 1", "count":"10"},
      {"id":"2", "sentiment":"0", "name":"Company 2", "count":"5"},
      {"id":"3", "sentiment":"0", "name":"Company 3", "count":"7"}   
   ],
   [
      {"id":"1", "sentiment":"1", "name":"Company 1", "count":"3"},
      {"id":"2", "sentiment":"1", "name":"Company 2", "count":"2"},
      {"id":"3", "sentiment":"1", "name":"Company 3", "count":"4"}   
   ]
]
```

How can I loop through this data in order to have two tables as shown below:

```
id     Company     sentiment      count
1      Company 1        0           10
2      Company 2        0            5
3      Company 3        0            7

id     Company     sentiment      count
1      Company 1        1           3
2      Company 2        1           2
3      Company 3        1           4
```

I have started this but got stuck:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
  $.each(obj, function(i, obj_item){
     $.each(obj_item, function(j, item){
    // got stuck here                   
     })
})
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *stuck*?

Comment: To my understanding, the data is already in the form you want it to be.

Comment: You should check out a framework like https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/ which will make your templating much cleaner and efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...
http://jsfiddle.net/kbVg4/

```
var table = '';
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    //One table per subset
    table += '<table>';

    //Table headers
    table += '<tr><th>Id</th><th>Company</th><th>Sentiment</th><th>Count</th></tr>';

    //Looping over the subset
    for(var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){
        table += '<tr>';
        table += '<td>'+data[i][j]['id']+'</td>';
        table += '<td>'+data[i][j]['name']+'</td>';
        table += '<td>'+data[i][j]['sentiment']+'</td>';
        table += '<td>'+data[i][j]['count']+'</td>';
        table += '</tr>';
    }
    table += '</table>';
}

//Use the appropriate ID.
$('body').append(table);
```

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: He's using jQuery. Might as well make some use of $.each etc.

Comment: If he understood `each` he wouldn't have stuck on it! Hence I used the for loops and array notifications so that he gets to know whats going on!

Comment: I was under the impression that he was stuck with the actual dynamic HTML element of the problem. He has the code for the loops already, using $.each

Answer (score 1):

here u go..

```
var data= "your show json array in question";

var str="";
 $.each(data, function(i, obj_item){
    str+="<table border='1'>";
     str+="<tr><td>id</td><td>sentiment</td><td>name</td><td>count</td>";
    $.each(obj_item, function(i1, obj){

        str+="<tr><td>"+obj.id+"</td><td>"+obj.sentiment+"</td><td>"+obj.name+"</td><td>"+obj.count+"</td>";
       str+="</tr>";
    });
     str+="</table>";

});

 $('div').html(str);//replace with your selector
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fb5uR/) here

Comment: Great fiddle.. @Asker - just rearrange his `<td>" + obj.id...` and switch the place of `obj.name` with `obj.sentiment` and it'll match your layout.